# SUM each row then show the result in new field on every each row

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have this table name "History":

```
------------------------------------------------
| id | account_id |  amount  | type | date
------------------------------------------------
| 1  |     3      |   100    | topup| 2018-01-01
------------------------------------------------
| 2  |     2      |   50     | topup| 2018-01-02
------------------------------------------------
| 3  |     3      |   -2     | usage| 2018-01-03
------------------------------------------------
| 4  |     3      |   -1     | usage| 2018-01-04
------------------------------------------------
| 5  |     2      |   -1     | usage| 2018-01-05
------------------------------------------------
| 6  |     3      |   -2     | usage| 2018-01-06
------------------------------------------------
```

I want to create query to calculate every each row by account_id for whowing the current balance for every account like this :

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| id | account_id |  amount  | type |    date   | balance
---------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |     3      |   100    | topup| 2018-01-01| 100
---------------------------------------------------------
| 2  |     2      |   50     | topup| 2018-01-02| 50
---------------------------------------------------------
| 3  |     3      |   -2     | usage| 2018-01-03| 98
---------------------------------------------------------
| 4  |     3      |   -1     | usage| 2018-01-04| 97
---------------------------------------------------------
| 5  |     2      |   -1     | usage| 2018-01-05| 49
---------------------------------------------------------
| 6  |     3      |   -2     | usage| 2018-01-06| 94
---------------------------------------------------------
```

i have try this :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT id, SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY id, account_id) AS balance
  FROM history
  GROUP BY account_id
) as foo
ORDER BY date;
```

but i got the field balance not have correct result, any clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9218c2ad97a8a32a659fa44ae72a185a)

```
SELECT
    *,
    SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY date)
FROM
    history
ORDER BY id
```

1. Create partitions for your `accounts_id`s
2. Order them by `date`
3. Cumulative `SUM()` now works, but current order is `(account_id, date)`
4. Reorder them by `id`